# Conditional onDuplicateKeyUpdate in Jooq

Tags: postgresql, scala, jooq, on-duplicate-key

I tried to use the jooq dsl for an insert/update query.
We have a unique (MemberId, GroupId) combination in our table, and a group membership Enum.
On sending a subscription request with (MemberId, GroupId, RoleEnum)
The query should insert a new entry to the db, but if the MemberId, GroupId combination already exists - then only update the entry if the new RoleEnum is larger than the existing one.

I failed to do this using one query with the jooq Dsl, so instead I had to use two queries (get, then insert or update accordingly) but then I lose the atomicity of the operation...

Is there a way to do this with one query with the jooqDsl?

Answer (score 3):

jOOQ emulates PostgreSQL 9.5's support for the `ON CONFLICT` clause via:

- `insertInto(...).values(...).onDuplicateKeyUpdate()...` of the MySQL syntax. This is possible only if your table is generated with explicit primary key information on it. (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5093, since jOOQ 3.8)
- `mergeInto(...).key(...).values(...)` of the H2 syntax. With this syntax, you can providean explicit key column list specification, so the code generator is not needed to provide constraint meta information. (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4464, since jOOQ 3.7).

Unfortunately, there is not yet any native `ON CONFLICT` support in jOOQ.

Comment: What does emulate mean? Does it generate the proper code but the jOOQ DSL looks different, or does it generate different SQL but the behavior of it maps to that of the `ON CONFLICT` definitions as defined in the http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html ?

Comment: @Yaneeve: The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause is MySQL specific. But its semantics can be emulated on PostgreSQL by generating an equivalent `ON CONFLICT` clause. I.e. the `onDuplicateKeyUpdate()` clause in the jOOQ DSL will work on both databases. Natively on MySQL, and "emulated" on PostgreSQL.

Comment: @LukasEder is there a way to specify the keys to use in the on conflict or does Jooq try to check any unique constraints and add those?

Comment: @jmluy: Yes of course. Mind asking a new question, I can provide an explicit answer there...